# How to get linkedIn connections using javascript API?

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I am trying following code but it doesn't works for me.

```
//loading linkedin library
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
 api_key: *******
 authorize: true
</script>
//and making api request below
<script>
IN.API.Connections("me")
.result(function(data){
    alert(data);
});
</script>
```

I can't get an alert box, this means **IN.API.Connections** won't run and I am not getting any error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define some javascript function in your script to actually do something with the results you get back from the API. The alert box simply displays the data you get back.

The most basic call to fetch connections in JSAPI would look something like this:

```
IN.API.Connections("me")
    .result(doMyThing)
```

Where "doMyThing" is simply a javascript function that will handle and process the results that get returned.

There's also a document detailing this call on the LinkedIn Developer site: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/inapiconnections

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
 api_key: *******
 authorize: true
 scope: r_basicprofile r_network
</script>
```